# ddrescue image too large

Tags: data-recovery, corruption, ddrescue

3Tb HDD is corrupt. I tried using ddrescue to create an image and a logfile on another 3TB HDD (only one I had). I got a write error after about 2.7T (actual capacity of the 3TB). Image file and log appear ok.

My question is can I still restore from the image file even though it might be truncated? I'm ok with retrieving 99.9% of my data.

Or should I repeat but write the log to USB, or repeat without log file, is the same size drive still too small?

Thanks in advance,.

Answer (score 1):

If you use another same-sized drive you'll need to be able to write the rescue image to the raw disk rather than as a file in the filesystem on that disk.

The log file will need to be stored elsewhere. (Ideally don't bother running `ddrescue` without a log file. It's used to track the sectors that need revisiting.)

```
broken=sdb
replacement=sdc
ddrescue "/dev/$broken" "/dev/$replacement" /mnt/usb/logfile
```